# Dynamic HTML form element array in IE8 issue

Tags: javascript, dom

I am facing an issue while handling dynamic HTML textbox array element in IE. This is what I am doing:

I am creating new textbox array elements on the fly using DOM (document.createElement)... it will be like this:

```
element = document.createElement('input');
element.setAttribute('type','text');
element.setAttribute('name','txtBox[]');
element.setAttribute('value','somevalue');
```

Then, I am submitting the form with GET(Yes, I needed this) as action. In the URL, the textbox array values are URL encoded, like:

?txtBox%5B%5D=17&txtBox%5B%5D=22

It's happening only in IE, FF and Chrome are fine.

Comment: Can you use the `element.name="txtBox[]";` form?

Comment: So on the server-side what does the txtBox field contain when posting with IE8?

Comment: @Passerby, not working

Comment: @kjetilh it's just numeric values ...

Comment: When testing locally with IE (IE 9 but using developer tools to imitate IE 8) I get an array when accessing the $_GET contents using the query arguments **?txtBox%5B%5D=17&txtBox%5B%5D=22**. Like so `array (size=1)
  'txtBox' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '17' (length=2)
      1 => string '22' (length=2)
`